# Is safe create partitions within .vdi to install Ubuntu Desktop/Server through VirtualBox? With and without LVM?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox, hard-drive, lvm

For some laptops I installed Ubuntu `Desktop` and `Server` - 20.04 - through `VirtualBox`, normally taking all the disk space defined and available through the `.vdi` file. Until here all is ok.

Now I am going to install Ubuntu directly in some PC Desktops. So now is time to use partitions, therefore I want first get some practice and experience. Sadly I can't use `GParted` in `VirtualBox` how I could do in a real hard disk - pls correct me if I am wrong - so I must use the own tools available through the `Ubuntu Live .iso` file - it for Desktop and Server environments. I read many tutorials about how to create/manage the partitions for Desktop and Server environments, such as:

- [Creating Linux Partitions](https://averagelinuxuser.com/linux-partitioning-recommendations/)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 Server Installation](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-server-installation)

Where they use the own tools available of Ubuntu. Well I want try to test many approaches, even including and not `LVM` suggested in other post:

- [Define partitions to install Linux but considering Security and Administration aspects/concerns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696422/define-partitions-to-install-linux-but-considering-security-and-administration-a)

Therefore

- Is safe create partitions within .vdi to install Ubuntu Desktop/Server through VirtualBox?
- With and without LVM?

I don't want make a mess (really do a harm) in the host's hard disk

**Note** some laptops (the Host) have the hard-disk based on `HDD` and `SSD` - perhaps it is important to take in consideration.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use GParted in VirtualBox. Have you tried?

Comment: When you install Ubuntu in VirtualBox, using the default installation using the whole vdi disks, the installation process creates partition(s) that cover the whole disk. Yes it is safe. If you are planning to install Ubuntu on real computers, please don't create unnecessary partitions. Just use the standard install without going into **Something Else**. If you have special needs for creating specific partitions, please edit your question and explain.

Comment: @Tilman how? consider it prior to install ubuntu - I can use GParted within VirtualBox after to had installed Ubuntu, it for the scenario when I give more size to the `.vdi` file and then is mandatory expand Ubuntu with GParted.

Comment: @user68186 partitions to be created for security and administration purposes such as mentioned in the 3rd link. it mostly for server environment

Comment: Just connect a bootable GParted image as a virtual CDROM to your VirtualBox VM and then boot the VM from it.

Comment: @Tilman , such as is inserted the `.iso` file for `Guest Additions`, right? - even with or without GParted, is safe for the HD (`.vdi`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## As safe as your own hands

Yes it is safe to create partitions in `.vdi` virtual disks. If you start with empty disks you have nothing to worry about. If the disks contain data a simple mistake can cost you your data.

You can create partitions during the Ubuntu installation process. For Desktop installation, the selection is marked as **Something Else**. For Server installation the selection is marked as **Manual**.

If you want to create the partitions before hand, you may use Gparted or other partition tools.

If you want to practice using Gparted on a virtual disks inside VirtualBox, first [add a second virtual disks](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-new-drives-to-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine/) to your Ubuntu virtual machine. Then use Gparted to manipulate the second virtual disk.

Once you are happy with the partitions of the second disk. Detach the disk from the Ubuntu VM and use this disk as an existing disk to install the Ubuntu server. See [how to add an existing `.vdi` file to a VirtualBox](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-add-disk.html).

If the disks go bad, just delete the `.vdi` files and start again.

Hope this helps